# error in import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService; aidl.exe

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i'm new newbie, i get i error in
 `import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;`
and i search in many website and also in `stackoverflow` and i can't find solution this error happen to me in all apps who has inapp purchase

`console`

```
[2016-04-18 18:23:08 - com.companyname.uponlyGP] aidl.exe E  3204  4224 io_delegate.cpp:102] Error while creating directories: Invalid argument
[2016-04-18 18:23:14 - com.companyname.uponlyGP] aidl.exe E  4704  1984 io_delegate.cpp:102] Error while creating directories: Invalid argument
[2016-04-18 18:23:17 - com.companyname.uponlyGP] aidl.exe E  3048  4848 io_delegate.cpp:102] Error while creating directories: Invalid argument
[2016-04-18 18:26:46 - com.companyname.uponlyGP] aidl.exe E  3580  4224 io_delegate.cpp:102] Error while creating directories: Invalid argument
```

you can see too screenshot of error
[this is error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yO96.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution remove build tools 24.0.0 PREVIEW